# Can multiple selection with React.createtef() be used?

Tags: reactjs

Can I use multiple selection with `React.createref()?` It returns undefined.

```xml
<div>
    <label>
      Pilih Skill :{" "}
      <select multiple ref={this.inputSkill}>
        <option value="Front-end" key="1">Front-end</option>
        <option value="Back-end" key="2">Back-end</option>
        <option value="Dev-Ops" key="13">Dev-Ops</option>
        <option value="Full Stack" key="41">Full Stack</option>
      </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: React.createRef should be referred to a single element. What's a problem? What you want to achieve? Did you try `this.inputSkill.current`?

Comment: my mentor want me use React.createRef for multiple
but i just can use single element